# Loop com "for" em um formulário com conjuntos de campos iguais

Tags: php, formulário, loop

Tenho uma captura de dados de um formulário onde são campos 5 conjuntos de campos iguais. Quero que na hora de capturar para meu array, eu não precise repetir:

```
array[1] = post1, array[2] = post2
```

Sei que dá para usar um `for`:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    lista[$i][..........]=post[........$i]
}
```

Meu código está assim:

```
$lista[1]['nome']=$_POST['nome1'];
$lista[1]['curso']=$_POST['curso1'];
$lista[1]['idade']=$_POST['idade1'];
$lista[1]['sexo']=$_POST['sexo1'];

$lista[2]['nome']=$_POST['nome2'];
$lista[2]['curso']=$_POST['curso2'];
$lista[2]['idade']=$_POST['idade2'];
$lista[2]['sexo']=$_POST['sexo2'];

$lista[3]['nome']=$_POST['nome3'];
$lista[3]['curso']=$_POST['curso3'];
$lista[3]['idade']=$_POST['idade3'];
$lista[3]['sexo']=$_POST['sexo3'];

$lista[4]['nome']=$_POST['nome4'];
$lista[4]['curso']=$_POST['curso4'];
$lista[4]['idade']=$_POST['idade4'];
$lista[4]['sexo']=$_POST['sexo4'];

$lista[5]['nome']=$_POST['nome5'];
$lista[5]['curso']=$_POST['curso5'];
$lista[5]['idade']=$_POST['idade5'];
$lista[5]['sexo']=$_POST['sexo5'];
```

Acredito que preciso usar uma concatenacao no nome do post, estou colocando a sintax errada aqui, como fica isso?

Comment: Não entendi o que vc quer...

Comment: O que é `exploid`?

Comment: Acho que é [explode($dinamite)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 7):

```
$campos = array( 'nome', 'curso', 'idade', 'sexo' );
$lista = array();

for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
   foreach ( $campos as $campo ) {
      $lista[$i][$campo] = $_POST[$campo.$i];
   }
}
```

Comment: mto bom seu codigo tambem, é isso mesmo

Answer (score 5):

Para transformar esse código em um único passe o indice `$i` na hora de atribuir os valores como abaixo:

```
$lista = array();
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
   $lista[$i]['nome'] = $_POST['nome'.$i];
   $lista[$i]['curso']=$_POST['curso'.$i];
   $lista[$i]['idade']=$_POST['idade'.$i];
   $lista[$i]['sexo']=$_POST['sexo'.$i];
}
```

Comment: resolvido, obrigado!  deu certinho